awslogs docker driver cannot get credentials on an on-premises server
I'm trying to use the awslogs driver on a dockerised applicaiton running on a non-aws server (or locally for debugging). I pass in the docker-compose.yaml file the environmental variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY which are correctly added to the container (i verified). However the container fails to start with error:
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: operation error CloudWatch Logs: CreateLogStream, get identity: get credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, request canceled, context deadline exceeded.
From my local terminal with the same AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY I can send logs to aws cloudwatch. What could be the issue?
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    image: etiket_app
    volumes:
      - ~/.aws:/root/.aws
    environment:
       - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
       - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
       - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=...
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: "test_group"
        awslogs-region: "eu-north-1"
        awslogs-stream: "test_stream"


were you able to resolve the problem? I have the same problem and neither environment variables nor .aws/credentials work.
